# пустой лог vlc при обнаружении движения

Tags: vlc

выполняю команду

vlc.exe --video-filter=motiondetect -vv >logfile.txt "файл"

logfile.txt создаётся, но туда ничего не записывается
как получить данные обнаружения движения в плеере?

Answer (score 0):

```
vlc.exe --video-filter=motiondetect "файл" --verbose=2 --file-logging --logfile=log.txt
```